# Separar ddd do telefone com instrução SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dql, ddl

Tenho uma tabela com campos DDD e Telefone.
Alguns foram cadastrados corretamente, outros o ddd está junto do telefone e preciso separar.

**TABELA**

```
+--------------------+
|   DDD  | Telefone  |  
+--------------------+     
|   47   | 89876543  | ---> ok
+--------------------+    
|  NULL  |4799843838 | ---> ajustar
+--------------------+    
|  NULL  |04799843838| ---> ajustar
+--------------------+
```

Como poderia fazer para atualizar meu banco de dados usando instrução SQL para colocar o DDD no campo correto, pois ele está junto ao telefone, só que deveria entrar no lugar do valor NULL.
Considerando também que tem que remover o `0` da esquerda (quando houver)?

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer um select, manipular as strings deste select, ver se o registro está ok, caso negativo, dar um update na linha separando o DDD do Telefone, consegue fazer isso?  Se possível, passe o schema da sua tabela https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=separate+column+in+2+columns+sql

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, mas não conheço muito a parte de programação e manipulação de dados. É uma tabela simples, que tem um ID (int) e as colunas DDD e Telefone são Varchar.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode remover todos os espaços e palavras `NULL`, caso não tenha um `0` a esquerda, adicione um, então format a string:

```
DECLARE @Telefones AS TABLE (
    [DDD Telefone] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Telefones VALUES ('47 89876543')
INSERT INTO @Telefones VALUES ('NULL 4799843838')
INSERT INTO @Telefones VALUES ('NULL 04799843838');

WITH CTE_Telefones AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([DDD Telefone], 'NULL', ''), ' ', '') AS  [DDD Telefone]
    FROM @Telefones
), CTE_Telefones_Zero AS (
    SELECT 
        CAST(CASE CHARINDEX('0', [DDD Telefone])
            WHEN 1 THEN [DDD Telefone] 
            ELSE '0' + [DDD Telefone]
        END AS VARCHAR(MAX)) as [DDD Telefone]
    FROM CTE_Telefones
)

SELECT 
    '(' + SUBSTRING([DDD Telefone], 1, 3) + ') ' + 
    SUBSTRING([DDD Telefone], 3, LEN([DDD Telefone]) - 7) + '-' + 
    SUBSTRING([DDD Telefone], LEN([DDD Telefone]) - 3, 4) AS [DDD Telefone]
FROM CTE_Telefones_Zero
```

A saída do SQL será algo do gênero:

```
(047) 7898-6543
(047) 7998-3838
(047) 7998-3838
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode esta fazendo desta forma :

```
declare @contatos table
(
    ID_CONTATO_TELEFONE int,
    ID_CONTATO int,
    TIPO_TELEFONE varchar(1),
    DDD varchar(5),
    NUMERO varchar(100),
    IND_SITUACAO varchar(1),
    OBSERVACAO varchar(100)
)

insert into @contatos
values(1,1,'F','011','98876667','A',''),
(2,2,'F','','1198876667','A',''),
(3,3,'C','','01198876667','A',''),
(4,4,'C','','08798687667','A',''),
(5,5,'C','','(51)988765473','A',''),
(6,6,'C','','(051)98876543','A',''),
(7,7,'C','','(051)988765439 - ramal 3245','A',''),
(8,7,'C','','(051)88765439 - ramal 3245','A','');





select ID_CONTATO_TELEFONE,ID_CONTATO, TIPO_TELEFONE, 
case when DDD is not null and DDD <> '' then DDD 
     else case when SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,2) = '(0' then SUBSTRING(NUMERO,2,3) 
               when SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,1) = '(' then ('0' +SUBSTRING(NUMERO,2,2))
               when SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,1) = '0' then SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,3) 
               else  ('0' +SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,2)) 
        end 
end as DDD,
case when DDD is not null and DDD <> '' then NUMERO
     else case when SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,2) = '(0' then   case  when ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(NUMERO,6,9)) = 1 then SUBSTRING(NUMERO,6,9) else SUBSTRING(NUMERO,6,8) end
                   when SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,1) = '(' then  case  when ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(NUMERO,5,9)) = 1 then SUBSTRING(NUMERO,5,9) else SUBSTRING(NUMERO,5,8) end
                   when  SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,1) = 0 then  case  when ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(NUMERO,4,9)) = 1 then SUBSTRING(NUMERO,4,9) else SUBSTRING(NUMERO,4,8) end 
                   else NUMERO
            end  
end as NUMERO,
IND_SITUACAO, OBSERVACAO from @contatos;
```

Use o `case` e o `SUBSTRING` para retira as partes que você precisa da `string`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, pelo que pude ver essa é a solução que eu preciso, mas deu um erro pois em alguns numeros existe '(' ou ')' como por exemplo (51)98876543 ou (051)98876543

Comment: @Brupikk, você pode usar o `SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,1)  = '('` ou `SUBSTRING(NUMERO,1,2)  = '(0'` para verificar isso.

Comment: @Brupikk, alterei a resposta..

Comment: Obrigado Marconcilio! Como eu faço para ignorar o registro caso ele tenha letras no meio e nesse caso deixar como está? (algumas pessoas colocam escrito Ramal ou outra coisa após o numero, esses vamos ignorar e deixar como está, dessa forma está dando erro por causa das letras)

Comment: @Brupikk, isso vai ser um pouco complicado. uma dica é verificar se os telefones são ainda com 8 dígitos, caso seja você pode fazer o tratamento para retira o DDD e depois os próximos 8 caracteres ou 9 no caso e ignorar o restante, as letra que você fala vem sempre depois do numero?

Comment: pois é, complicado. heheh.. falei com eles, e pediram então pra só ajustar se estiver na mascara (51)99999999 ou (051)99999999. Se estiver de um desses dois jeitos, tirar o ddd do numero e colocar no campo ddd. Qualquer outra coisa deixar como está

Comment: @Brupikk, veja a edição que fiz, a parti dele faça a alteração necessária.

Comment: Valeu!! vou tentar

Comment: Consegui!!! Valeu as dicas!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você você pode usar o SubString:

```
UPDATE nome_tabela SET
   DDD = SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 1 FOR 2)
  ,Telefone = SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 3 FOR 9) 
 WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 1 FOR 2) AS INTEGER) = 47;
```

Aqui testando se começa com 0:

```
UPDATE nome_tabela SET
   DDD = SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 2 FOR 3)
  ,Telefone = SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 4 FOR 10) 
 WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(Telefone FROM 1 FOR 1) AS INTEGER) = 0;
```

Faça os testes, estou sem pc, respondendo pelo celular!

Answer (score 1):

```
select
 left( convert(bigint,replace( replace([Telefone],' ',''),'NULL','')),2) as DDD,
 Substring( convert(varchar(255),convert(bigint,replace( replace([Telefone],' ',''),'NULL',''))),3,11) as Telefone
 from Telefone
```

Comment: Poderia explicar porque isso funciona?

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso tinha 2 problemas

- Identificar se era um numero de celular
- Atualizar colocando o digito 9.

**Atualizar o Tipo de Celular**

```
UPDATE Telefone SET descricao = "Celular" 
WHERE numero LIKE "(%" AND SUBSTRING(numero,5,1) IN ('6', '7', '8', '9');
```

**Limpar a formatacao (somente dos antigos)**

```
UPDATE Telefone SET numero = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(numero,'(',''),'-',''),')','') 
WHERE descricao = "Celular" AND LENGTH(numero) = 13;
```

**Formater adicionando o 9 (somente dos antigos - lenth = 10)**

```
UPDATE Telefone SET numero = CONCAT('(',SUBSTRING(numero,1,2), ')9', SUBSTRING(numero, 3, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(numero, 7, 4)) 
WHERE descricao = "Celular" AND LENGTH(numero) = 10;
```

> Atualmente pela anatel somente os números de telefone que iniciem com
>   6,7,8,9 são números de celular.